# Attach unique values for multiple, but identical objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on angular 6. I have an array of objects(got from an API). The objects have similar properties and I want to attach different values to each element with the property name of "value".BUT the values I‘m giving are being attached to all elements of the array.

Tried to give a unique id for each object to differentiate one from the other. But a single unique key is assigned to all similar object elements.

```
uniqueFields = [
    {
      name: "ProformaInvoiceNumber",
      type: "text",
      options: Array(0),
      isCommon: false,
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: "ProformaInvoiceDate",
      type: "date",
      options: Array(0),
      isCommon: false,
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: "ProformaInvoiceNumber",
      type: "text",
      options: Array(0),
      isCommon: false,
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: "ProformaInvoiceDate",
      type: "date",
      options: Array(0),
      isCommon: false,
      required: true
    }];


//received values from html form
recievedValues = [1, {name }, 2, { obj2 }];

//give values to my uniqueFields from the array recievedValues 
this.uniqueFields.foreach((element, i) => {
  element.value = recievedValues[i];//both arrays have the same length 
});
```

Was expecting an array with objects, and each objects having property "value" and the value from the corresponding array element. Instead, I am getting this...

```js
uniqueFields = [
  {
    name: "ProformaInvoiceNumber",
    type: "text",
    options: Array(0),
    isCommon: false,
    required: true,
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "ProformaInvoiceDate",
    type: "date",
    options: Array(0),
    isCommon: false,
    required: true,
    value: { obj2 }
  },
  {
    name: "ProformaInvoiceNumber",
    type: "text",
    options: Array(0),
    isCommon: false,
    required: true,
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: "ProformaInvoiceDate",
    type: "date",
    options: Array(0),
    isCommon: false,
    required: true,
    value: { obj2 }
  }];
```

Comment: Your question is totally unclear and the code doesn't seem very valid. Please read [ask] before posting a question, and provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue (a snippet in your answer should be enough)

Comment: I also took the liberty of editing the tags of your question : most of them were not suited and were simply polluting the tags.

Comment: If you can add a new property on the fly with javascript, you can't change the type of your object this way with a new property  with typescript. You need to type your array with an interface/class including the 'value' property. I don't even understand how you get results with your code as copying it, i get errors.

Comment: @Maryannah  Thank you for editing the question. What part of it is not clear? I have tried to make it clear as much as possible. You see the second array uniqueFields should get value property and a unique value but it's being duplicated for objects with similar property.  Like the two objects with the name "ProformaInvoiceDate" took the same value.

Comment: @NathanGL I don't get what you're trying to do. Just give the original data, the expected result, and your current result, and I'll be able to answer you with that !

Comment: @Maryannah what I‘m trying to do is simply give values for each object in my array from another array. But the values are being duplicated. I want each object to get a corresponding value from the array recievedValues. I hope this makes it clear. Basically, I want to uniquely identify each object in the uniqueFields array.

Comment: @NathanGL `Just give the original data, the expected result, and your current result, and I'll be able to answer you with that` !

Answer (score 1):

was working on it for a while and here is my solution. Agularjs had its own way of identifying objects using $$hashKey on ng-repeat and current angular doesn't incorporate that, therefore for the array containing similar object elements I had to create an interface and use a unique object to identify them.

```
export interface Field {  
    name:string;
    type:string;
    options:string[];
    isCommon:boolean;
    value:any;  
}
```

And use the new object before attaching value to the objects in the array

```
var fieldObject: Field =  {
   name: this.uniqueFields[0]['name'],
   type: this.uniqueFields[0]['type'],
   options:  this.uniqueFields[0]['options'], 
   isCommon: this.uniqueFields[0]['isCommon'],
   value: null
}
```